# How to pass a props by the style of components react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, styled-components, react-props

I'm trying to make a dark theme button theme in react native, so I need to change the image through BackgroundImage through the theme provider, however when I try to move the props forward it just doesn't work.

**index.js**

```
import { Background } from "./styles";
<Background source={props.backgroundImage} />
```

**style.js**

```
export const Background = styled.ImageBackground.attrs(
require(props => props.theme.backgroundImage))``;
```

**my app.js**:

```
import React from "react"; 
import themes from './src/themes'; 
<ThemeProvider theme={themes.light}> 
  <NavigationContainer> 
    <MainStacks /> 
  </NavigationContainer> 
 </ThemeProvider>
```

**My light.js**:

```
export default {backgroundImage: "../../../assets/background.png"}
```

**It returns the error**: `Error: Cannot find module 'function (props) { return props.theme.backgroundImage; } '`

Comment: Please add what is actually happening.  Try and explain more what do you mean by "it just doesn't work."

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner and I thought the mistake would be simple for the more advanced.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to pass a props to React Native's ImageBackground that would be an image defined by styled components with ThemeProvider.

Comment: It returns the error:
Error: Cannot find module 'function (props) {
   return props.theme.backgroundImage;
} '

Comment: Please edit your post to include the relevant information, don't put it in the comments.